# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ClientConfigData"). Expected elements are <{}clientConfigData>

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am getting the error as mentioned. Adding code snippet to get more about what am I doing. Please have a look and help. Thanks in advance.
My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClientConfigData>
    <requestType>type1</requestType>
    <refreshEnable>false</refreshEnable>
    <compressionEnable>false</compressionEnable>
    <transformationEnable>true</transformationEnable>
...
</ClientConfigData>
```

My Java:

```
@XmlRootElement 
public class ClientConfigData {

    private String requestType;
    private boolean refreshEnable;
    private boolean compressionEnable;
    private boolean transformationEnable;
...
}
```

And here, I am creating java object from xml:

```
File configFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("ClientRegistration.xml").getFile());
JAXBContext jaxbContext;

try {
    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClientConfigData.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  
    ClientConfigData configData= (ClientConfigData) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(configFile);
    System.out.println(configData);
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: change question title to something meaningful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a qualified root element name to the `@XmlRootElement` annotation. In your case it will be:

`@XmlRootElement(name = "ClientConfigData")`

By default `JAXB` searches for `clientConfigData` (with the lower-case first letter).

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks